# How to write class required for serializing object for JSON response in particular format

Tags: c#, json, serialization, time-series, dataset

How to write class to have serialized object in the format given below.

```json
{
    "Availability" : Yes,
    "variable1": [        ["2022-01-01T00:00:00Z", 1.23, "kg", "good"],
        ["2022-01-02T00:00:00Z", 2.34, "kg", "good"],
        ["2022-01-03T00:00:00Z", 3.45, "kg", "good"],
        ["2022-01-04T00:00:00Z", 4.56, "kg", "fair"],
        ["2022-01-05T00:00:00Z", 5.67, "kg", "fair"]
         .
         .
         . N rows
    
    ],
    "Availability" : No,
    "variable2": [        ["2022-01-01T00:00:00Z", 10.0, "m", "good"],
        ["2022-01-02T00:00:00Z", 20.0, "m", "good"],
        ["2022-01-03T00:00:00Z", 30.0, "m", "good"],
        ["2022-01-04T00:00:00Z", 40.0, "m", "fair"],
        ["2022-01-05T00:00:00Z", 50.0, "m", "fair"]
         .
         .
         . N rows
    ]
}
```

My data is coming as a dataset via dll file.

dll file gives response in dataset as below:

```
VariableID| Timestamp            | Value| Units | Quality | Availability
variable1 | 2022-01-01T00:00:00Z | 1.23 | kg    |  good   | Yes
.
.
. N rows
variable2 | 2022-01-01T00:00:00Z | 10.0 | m    |  fair    | No
.
.
. N rows
```

I am using NewtonSoft JSON serialise to convert object to JSON. I am trying to make that dll file accessible via web API. Any help on this much appreciated. I am no coder by profession just trying to make something out of nothing. Kindly excuse my mistakes.

Comment: Can you show the code you have tried so far and what is the problem? Or you want somebody to create an application for you?

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve] with a sample `DataSet` in some standard format such as XML or JSON?  It's not clear how the *response in dataset as below:* is loaded into an actual c# `DataSet`.  For instance, to save your sample DataSet as XML, you could follow the instructions from [Save a dataset as XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/save-a-dataset-as-xml) then [edit] your question to include the XML.

Comment: Also, your desired root JSON object contains **duplicate property names**, specifically `"Availability"` precedes each `"variableN"` named property.  Do you really want that?  While duplicate property names are allowed by the JSON standard, they are [discouraged](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259#section-4): *When the names within an object are not unique, the behavior of software that receives such an object is unpredictable...*.  You will also need to write your JSON manually using `JsonWriter` to get duplicate property names.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple tools that can help you converting JSON to a C# class to use for deserializing.

- Visual Studio's [Paste JSON or XML as classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/paste-json-xml?view=vs-2022)
- [JSON2CSharp](https://json2csharp.com/)

When I tried your JSON example in JSON2CSharp it complained about the values for "Availability". It wanted quotes around the values "Yes" and "No" to consider those strings. If they're meant to be a bool I suggest changing the values to "true" and "false" instead.

JSON2CSharp gave me a C# class like

```
public class Root
{
    public string Availability { get; set; }
    public List<List<object>> variable1 { get; set; }
    public List<List<object>> variable2 { get; set; }
}
```

I doubt variable1 and variable2 are meant to be properties of an object if variable<x> is a row in the dataset. The "List<List<object>>" would also be clunky to work with.

I recommend:

- make a class to represent a row from the dataset
- convert the dataset into a list of those objects
- serialize the list of objects to JSON

The names of each property of the class could match the column names from your dataset. You can use the same class again when you deserialize the list. I'm guessing at the datatypes of the properties, so you may need to change them.

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int VariableID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
    public string Units { get; set; }
    public string Quality { get; set; }
    public bool Availability { get; set; }
}
```